# iOS - how to animate subviews of an expandable uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, animation

i expand/de-expand a tableviewcell when the user clicks on it.
i do this by calling

```
[tableview beginUpdates];
[tableview endUpdates];
```

described here http://locassa.com/animate-uitableview-cell-height-change/
this will recalculate the heights of the cells without reloading the whole tableview.

i usually layout subviews of my custom tableviewcells in

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    _aTableViewCellSubView.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 10.f, self.frame.size.width, 20.f);
    ...
}
```

my naive approach was to define a BOOL flag in the custom tableViewCell

```
initiallyLayedOut = NO;
```

and set the subviews without animation if this flag is set to NO;
after inital layouting i would set it to YES, then always animate the subviews to their new positions/sizes.
but this does not really work, as layoutSubviews may get called many times (in my example after resizing the cell, it's call 4 times).

i am a quite experienced iOS-developer, but i can't find a nice solution to this problem...

cheers

Comment: What exactly does, "this does not really work" mean? What result does your current code give you? What subviews are you trying to move and/or resize?

Comment: "not really work" in this case means that we do not want to start the same  animation 4 times at once...

Answer (score 1):

Put your changes in-between

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellforRow...]

[tableview beginUpdates];
cell.subview.frame = CGRectMake....
[tableview endUpdates];
```

It'll be animated though

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellforRow...]

[tableview beginUpdates];
[cell layoutSubviews];
[tableview endUpdates];
```

Comment: thanks for answering...
layoutSubviews is called automatically, many times (not controllable)
that is the reason i don't want to start animations in there.

Answer (score -1):

instead of setting the frames of subviews in

`- (void)layoutSubviews`

i do it in

`- (void)setFrame(CGRect)frame`

the subviews now animate to their new positions.
furthermore, you can controll the animation duration by wrapping beginUpdates and endUpdates like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"myAnimationId" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

    //scroll cell to visible after update animations finished
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
        }
    }];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    [CATransaction commit];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

cheers